# Collision detection bug in Java applet

Tags: java, applet, collision-detection, java-2d

In my maze game applet I'm having a little bug. Collision detection works but sometimes my character can go into walls. More precisely it detects collision and moves the character into the wall. It happens very rare but still pretty annoying. It happens if I keep pressing the arrow keys too fast alternately (for example down and right in a corner). The thread sleeps 20ms if that matters and a tile is 20px*20px.

I think the bug is somewhere here.
Rect is around the character 20*20px and bigRect is 60*60px to check collision in advance and r is around the wall tiles also 20*20px.

```
public void checkCollision() {

    if (r.intersects(Hero.getBigRect()) && Hero.getRect().intersects(r)) {
        if (hero.isMovingUp() == true) {
            hero.stopUp();
            hero.setHeroY(tileY + 20);
        }
        if (hero.isMovingDown() == true) {
            hero.stopDown();
            hero.setHeroY(tileY - 20);
        }
        if (hero.isMovingLeft() == true) {
            hero.stopLeft();
            hero.setHeroX(tileX + 20);
        }
        if (hero.isMovingRight() == true) {
            hero.stopRight();
            hero.setHeroX(tileX - 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that your code is, for example, detecting that your hero has moved left into a wall and then, when you hit the button to move your hero right, the intersection code is still evaluating to true, so your character is shunted to the left into the wall. You need to change your code so that your hero is moved away from the wall, not simply moved in the direction opposite to the current key press.

Comment: By the way, your question might get a better response on the [Game Development Stack Exchange channel](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).